# Parsing a ListView item onclick to another activity and match a specific data from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, listview

Can anyone help me parse the ListView item on click to another activity preferably one that will get and match the parsed id with some JSON data. Am working on a volley library and will definitely want to get the related data of the specific item clicked.

```
        // Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            LinkedList<String> mLinked = new LinkedList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < DRUGS.length; i++) {
                    mLinked.add(DRUGS[i]);
            }

            setListAdapter(new MyListAdaptor(this, mLinked));

            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            // Start new intent by passing value
                            // End intent
                    }

            });
       }
```

I needed my value to be seen on another activity as

```
public class Activity2_view extends Activity {
```

// Collecting the values from MainActivity class
    TextView tvView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String ItemName = intent.getStringExtra("jsonId");

    tvView.setText("Your drug name is: "  + ItemName);
}
```

}

Comment: you want to get the text of the clicked item right?

Comment: Yes Zahan I needed the text then onClick it must fetch the other related details of the item clicked which are stored remotely in an SQL database. So far I have also managed to create a working JSON part. Am using the Google's volley lib which I can confess is very useful too, thanks to the Google Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // Start a new intent - get the id from the view and send to another activity for JSON
                            // selected item
                            String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrugIndexing_view.class);
                            // sending data to new activity
                            i.putExtra("product", product);
                            startActivity(i);
                            // End intent
                    }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, in your `getView()` method, you can set a tag to match the id of the JSON data you need to link up with.  For example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int jsonId;  // Set the view's tag to the ID of the JSON data
                 // you want to link it to.
    convertView.setTag(jsonId);
}
```

Then, in your `OnItemClickListener`:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Get the id from the view.
        int jsonId = (int) view.getTag();

        // Start new intent by passing value
        Intent newActivityIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class);
        newActivityIntent.putExtra("jsonId", jsonId);

        // Start it.
        startActivity(newActivityIntent);
    }
});
```

If you're using a `ViewHolder` in your `getView()` method for optimization purposes, the `ViewHolder` will be the tag of your view.  You will need to add a member property to the `ViewHolder` object that you can save the id with.

```
public class ViewHolder {
    private int mJsonId;
    private TextView mTextView;

    public void setId(int id) {
        mJsonId = id;
    }

    public int getJsonId() {
        return mJsonId;
    }
}
```

then

```
ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
int jsonId = viewHolder.getJsonId();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Andrew, kindly guide me on the getView() part; which part of the code block should it feature? Am still experiencing some crush when the item is clicked.

Comment: `getView()` is in your `MyListAdapter` class.  It's how your listview draws each list item

Comment: Ok, I just needed a simple explanation at the onItemClick() function. Am able to toast and view the item clicked well but how can I parse it to another activity without a crash? On my Activity2_view class updated above, I expect to capture it. From that point I believe having the value I can progress well. Check my updated code above.

Comment: Post your logcat if it's crashing, we need to see the error

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand of your code...

```
String stringId = mLinked.get(position);

Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
mIntent.putExtra(KEY,stringId)
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: using your code in the lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() function; I am getting an Error:(46, 51) error: local variable mLinked is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final.

Comment: Upto Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); the code is responding very well infact the item clicked can be showed onclick but that's not all I want.

Comment: yup thats bound to happen when you use inside inner Anonymous overriden instances. did you try making it final. [You can because that linkedlist reference will never be overriden], even better is to make mLinked a class level variable problem solved.